# Custom validation design php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How would you design something like this:

I have fields a, b, c, d, e, f, g that take integer values (eg. 0 to 1000).

I want to validate this fields against custom validation rules, and the user should be able to edit these rules.

Only one of the rules per validation, not multiple at once.

Rule examples (it's always one rule per validation):

- a <= 30
- b = c - d - a
- c = a
- d = min (a+b-c; a+b--f-c)

How would you design this? I dont need a ready to use Class, I just need a direction.

Comment: Why do you need users to be able to edit the validation rules?

Comment: because they want to :)

but i can limit it to user been able to choose what field gets which pre defined rule

Comment: Ok.. Do you want them to be able to set it once (like on a Settings page), or every time they're adding new rows to the table

Comment: it will only be set once

Comment: Ok, what about the fields. Will there be only 1 value for A, 1 for B etc or will there be multiple rows where they enter values for all fields

Comment: yes only 1 value for a, 1 for b etc. And what i need is to check if, for example, a equals a sum of b minus c. Another examples are written above - in the question.

Comment: Just realized what the big problem is, and right now, I actually don't have a good answer to how you should go about it... Will get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Database Overview

```
TABLE: rules

fieldname  |  fieldrule
--------------------------
a          |  <= 30
b          |  == $a + $c
c          |  != $a
d          |  > 50
e          |  < 50
f          |  == $d - $a

TABLE: fields

 a  | b  | c  | d  | e  | f
-----------------------------
 10 | 15 | 5  | 65 | 38 | 55      <-- Example row
 20 | 46 | 26 | 91 | 9  | 71      <-- Example row
```

The PHP code below is an example of how the page where you add fields could look like.

fields.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // RETRIEVE DATA
  $a = $_POST['field_a'];
  $b = $_POST['field_b'];
  $c = $_POST['field_c'];
  $d = $_POST['field_d'];
  $e = $_POST['field_e'];
  $f = $_POST['field_f'];

  $error = array();

  // GET FIELDS AND RULES FROM DB
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT fieldname, fieldrule FROM rules");
  if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
    // GO THROUGH EACH FIELD AND IT'S RULES
    while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
      eval('if (!($' . $get['fieldname'] . ' ' . $get['fieldrule'] . ')) { $error[] = \'Field <b>' . $get['fieldname'] . '</b> did not validate. The field must match the rule ' . $get['fieldrule'] . '\'; }');
    }
  }

  // CHECK IF ANY ERRORS WERE FOUND
  if (empty($error)) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO fields (a, b, c, d, e, f) VALUES ('" . $a . "', '" . $b . "', '" . $c . "', '" . $d . "', '" . $e . "', '" . $f . "')");
    echo '<div id="successful">' . "\n";
    echo '  <p>The new fields have been added to the database!</p>' . "\n";
    echo '</div>' . "\n";
  }
  // .. AND OUTPUT THEM IF THERE WAS
  else {
    echo '<div id="error">' . "\n";
    echo '  <h1>Some errors were found during the validation</h1>' . "\n";
    echo '  <ul>' . "\n";
    foreach ($error as $details) {
      echo '    <li>' . $details . '</li>' . "\n";
    }
    echo '  </ul>' . "\n";
    echo '</div>' . "\n";
  }
}

// GET RULES TO OUTPUT IN FORM
$rule = array();
$rules = mysql_query("SELECT fieldname, fieldrule FROM rules");
if (mysql_num_rows($rules)) {
  while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($rules)) {
    $field = $fetch['fieldname'];
    $rule[$field] = str_replace('$', '', $fetch['fieldrule']);
  }
}

?>
<div id="fields">
<form action="fields.php" method="post">
  <div class="field">
    <h2>Field A</h2>
    <span>Rule: a <?php echo $rule['a']; ?></span>
    <input type="text" name="field_a" size="20" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <h2>Field B</h2>
    <span>Rule: b <?php echo $rule['b']; ?></span>
    <input type="text" name="field_b" size="20" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <h2>Field C</h2>
    <span>Rule: c <?php echo $rule['c']; ?></span>
    <input type="text" name="field_c" size="20" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <h2>Field D</h2>
    <span>Rule: d <?php echo $rule['d']; ?></span>
    <input type="text" name="field_d" size="20" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <h2>Field E</h2>
    <span>Rule: e <?php echo $rule['e']; ?></span>
    <input type="text" name="field_e" size="20" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <h2>Field F</h2>
    <span>Rule: f <?php echo $rule['f']; ?></span>
    <input type="text" name="field_f" size="20" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Then just create a page where you let the admins edit the rules table, but make sure they add the fields in the rules as variables (with a preceding $) or add a preg_replace() function to do it automatically before it's added to the DB, or when you retrieve the rules.

The variables in the rules' got to be the same as the ones you use to retrieve the data from the fields.php form